# Can we define Bcc using Send-PnPMail

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, email, pnp-powershell, pnp

Can we define Bcc using [Send-PnPMail](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Send-PnPMail.html) cmdlet in PnP PowerShell?

Comment: Hi @johnGu. Check updates to my answer given below.

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation and GitHub source code, defining BCC using `Send-PnPMail` cmdlet is not supported.

Check below links form more information:

1. [SendMail.cs](https://github.com/pnp/powershell/blob/dev/src/Commands/Utilities/SendMail.cs)
2. [MailUtility](https://github.com/pnp/PnP-Sites-Core/blob/master/Core/OfficeDevPnP.Core/Utilities/MailUtility.cs) - create your own function based on this code.
3. [Send-PnPMail Parameters](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Send-PnPMail.html#parameters)

---

**Update**:

I have requested support for using BCC in PnP PowerShell and repository maintainers added it to the PnP PowerShell library.

This will be available with latest version of PnP PowerShell shortly.

Check this GitHub issue thread for more information: [[FEATURE] Support for BCC in Send-PnPMail cmdlet](https://github.com/pnp/powershell/issues/2677)